# A lot of errors in JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse, jboss-developer-studio

I installed Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio on Windows 8.1. In the Error Log view there are a lot of errors.

I do not know how can I fix them. Is there anyone guide me?

[image]

Comment: Is there anyone guide me?

Comment: Are you working behind proxy?

Comment: @dgolovin . I use VPN.

Comment: Your eclipse has no access to all those resources reported in Error Log View. Can you download them in browser? Try to load http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/configuration/ide-config.properties, do you see it?

Comment: @dgolovin - Thanks for your answer. I changed my VPN service and reinstalled it.those errors was solved, but now I have these new errors. plz look at this: Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.round' Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.number' Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.round' Duplicate template id: 'org.eclipse.wst.xslt.templates.xpath.number'

Comment: That seems to be eclipse issue, by name I would say it probably affects only content assist in xslt templates. Also it is worth to mention that there is always something in eclipse log view, it rarely stays empty for a long time.

Comment: @dgolovin Thank you for your answer.